# Loading plugin script only on required page?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have a plugin that is loading its .js on every page on my site.

I was able to filter out the plugin from loading, but i can't figure out how to specify the pages on which to load.

Plugin Code:

```
function A2A_SHARE_SAVE_head_script() {
     add_filter( 'addtoany_script_disabled', '__return_true' );
     $script_disabled = apply_filters( 'addtoany_script_disabled', false );
```

I need to be able to en queue the script on blog single post pages, the page template looks like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

And then in entry.php i manually call the plugin as follows:

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'social_sharing_buttons' ) ) { social_sharing_buttons(); } ?>
```

Comment: For clarity ... Are you trying to only enqueue JS on a singular (specific) page, or on any "single post page"?  And by "single post page" I am assuming you only want the JS loaded when you are viewing that post entry, but not on a blog page that lists all posts.  Yes?? Happy to offer advice once I understand these elements of your question.

Comment: Forgot to ask.... Did you write the plugin?  If not, naming it might aid the community in researching a solution for you.  If so, can you modify it? If not, can you verify whether or not wp_enqueue_scripts is being use (vs `add_action('wp_footer',....)`)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, it should disable the script from loading on anything other than single blog post pages without having to edit your templates:

```
add_filter('addtoany_script_disabled', 'disable_a2a_script_except_on_posts');
function disable_a2a_script_except_on_posts($disabled) {
    if (!is_single()) {$disabled = true;}
    return $disabled;
}
```